# How to read multiple lines in a template and substitute values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-substitution

I have a piece of standard text having multiple lines and some format like below:

```
owner: oracle
date_conditions: 1
    timezone: US/Eastern
    std_out_file: "/app/local/job.log"
    machine: rachost
```

I want to use this above text with machine and timezone being changed as per the need.
How can I use python to define this is a template and substitute various values?
I came across the substitution option in `string.Template`. But this seems to be working with a single line only.

Comment: This template should be read to be used else where, or this is the one you want to produce? I know you said read it, but you mention that you want to write it as well.

Comment: Which values should be replaced by which values? Why not use `%(key)s` (or the corresponding with `format`), thus having a better template to plug in a dictionary?!

Comment: @FlorianBernard i wanted to use this template and generate new text having similar format with new values for machine or timezone.I need to use this new text file to send it via mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `string.Template` class *can* handle strings consisting of multiple lines.

For example:

```
from string import Template

template = Template('''\
owner: oracle
date_conditions: 1
    timezone: $tz
    std_out_file: "/app/local/job.log"
    machine: $mach
''')

result = template.substitute(tz='US/Pacific', mach='foobar')
print(result, end='')
```

Prints:

```
owner: oracle
date_conditions: 1
    timezone: US/Pacific
    std_out_file: "/app/local/job.log"
    machine: foobar
```

Comment: This works fine and is exactly what i needed.
What is the purpose of end=' ' in the print statement?

Comment: The `end=''`suppresses the newline `print()` adds by default. It's not needed because the template string ends with one. If the lines of the template were read from a file, the last line would likely also have one, so you might want to use this in that scenario, as well.

Comment: how can we send the 'result' to an email.

Comment: @vivek: Sorry, but that's a completely unrelated question and it doesn't sound like you've made any attempt to do it yourself. Suggest you take a look at the documentation of Python's [`smtplib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#module-smtplib) module.

Comment: i have a function for sending the email:
def sendjilmail(email_address='vievk@abc.com'):
    global glob_email_msg
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From']= 'check@abc.com'
    msg['To'] = email_address
    msg['Subject'] = 'missing file Email'
    msg.attach(MIMEText(glob_email_msg,'html'))
    s = smtplib.SMTP('mailhost.jpmchase.net')
    s.starttls()
    s.sendmail('check@abc.com', email_address, msg.as_string())
    s.quit()


But the issue is that it is not retaining the exact format of the file with spaces as required.